# How to use enable_if for out-of-line definition for a template class member

Tags: c++, class, templates, template-specialization

I am trying to understand the usage of `enable_if` but I do have few difficulties in the same. Here I have written a test code that doesn't seem to work as intended.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Base{
 public:
  template <typename U>
  U Compute(U a, U b);
};

using AddOperation = Base<int>;

template<>
template<typename U>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, bool>::value, U>::type
AddOperation::Compute(U a, U b){
  return a + b;
}

int main(){
  Base<int> b;
  std::cout << b.Compute<int>(10, 2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << b.Compute<bool>(true, false) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Intention: Don't want to enable Compute for `bool` type

but in the code above, it is working. How do I make sure that the Compute function for bool is not specialized by compiler?

**EDIT1**

Eventual goal is to enable `Compute` for U=bool for T=T1 and disable `Compute` for U=bool for T=T2. Here is another example code by which I am trying to achieve the same

```
#include <iostream>

enum class OpType{
  INT,
  BITWISE,
};

template <OpType T>
class Base{
 public:
  template <typename U>
  typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, bool>::value, U>::type 
  Compute(U a, U b); 
};

using AddOperation = Base<OpType::INT>;

template<>
template<typename U>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, bool>::value, U>::type
AddOperation::Compute(U a, U b){ 
  std::cout << a << "," << b << std::endl;
  return a + b;
}

using AndOperation = Base<OpType::BITWISE>;

template<>
template<typename U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, bool>::value, U>::type
AndOperation::Compute(U a, U b){
  return a & b;
}

int main(){
  AddOperation b;
  AndOperation a;
  std::cout << b.Compute<int>(10, 2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << a.Compute<bool>(true, true) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `enable_if` in the declaration too, as the definition did.

```
template <typename T>
class Base{
 public:
  template <typename U>
  typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, bool>::value, U>::type Compute(U a, U b);
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TGJgtzqrEYQ8quq8)

In fact, [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CngVxe4Qa0SeSBg4) rejects your current code as I expected, because the declaration and defintion don't match.

> error: out-of-line definition of 'Compute' does not match any declaration in 'Base'

---

**EDIT** (for your added question)

You can

```
template <OpType T>
class Base{
 public:
  template <typename U, OpType X = T>
  typename std::enable_if<
             (X == OpType::INT && !std::is_same<U, bool>::value) 
             || 
             (X == OpType::BITWISE && std::is_same<U, bool>::value), U
           >::type
  Compute(U a, U b); 
};

using AddOperation = Base<OpType::INT>;

template<>
template<typename U, OpType X>
typename std::enable_if<
           (X == OpType::INT && !std::is_same<U, bool>::value) 
           || 
           (X == OpType::BITWISE && std::is_same<U, bool>::value), U
         >::type
AddOperation::Compute(U a, U b){ 
  std::cout << a << "," << b << std::endl;
  return a + b;
}

using AndOperation = Base<OpType::BITWISE>;

template<>
template<typename U, OpType X>
typename std::enable_if<
           (X == OpType::INT && !std::is_same<U, bool>::value) 
           || 
           (X == OpType::BITWISE && std::is_same<U, bool>::value), U
         >::type
AndOperation::Compute(U a, U b){
  return a & b;
}
```

then

```
std::cout << b.Compute<int>(10, 2) << std::endl;       // fine
std::cout << a.Compute<bool>(true, true) << std::endl; // fine
std::cout << b.Compute<bool>(true, true) << std::endl; // error, no matching function
std::cout << a.Compute<int>(10, 2) << std::endl;       // error, no matching function
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/maUHIKEblIQTRviw)

Another approach is [class template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization), to seperate the implementation of `OpType::INT` and `OpType::BITWISE`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Understand the issue. Have added another requirement. Would love to know your input on the same.

Comment: @RachitAgrawal Answer revised.

Comment: Is it possible to do with a single function? Since `Compute` is anyway getting over-loaded, declaring two separate function seems extra.

Comment: @RachitAgrawal Like this? (Answer revised.)

Comment: Interesting but if enum class is extended, managing the code becomes really tough.

Comment: @RachitAgrawal Class template spcialization and seperate these implementation might be better.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really answer of your question but there is a better way to forbid `bool` argument for `Compute( T , T )` function for sake of readability.

```
template <typename T>
class Base{
 public:
  template <typename U>
  U Compute(U a, U b);

  bool Compute(bool , bool) = delete;
};
```

Comment: Nice solution. But my requirement is little more than what I had originally posted. Edited my question to explain my further requirement.

Comment: If you understood the other answers, it is easy, just add `&& std::is_same<your_intention>` in `std::enable_if`

Comment: That is boiling down to defining another Compute function inside the Base class. Was wondering if there is a better solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to disable it only for `bool` types, have the method implemented for the primary class template `Base<T>`. You need `enable_if` in the declaration of Compute() too.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Base{
 public:
  template <typename U>
  typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, bool>::value, U>::type Compute(U a, U b);
};

template<typename T>
template<typename U>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, bool>::value, U>::type
Base<T>::Compute(U a, U b){
  return a + b;
}

int main(){
  Base<int> b;
  std::cout << b.Compute<int>(10, 2) << std::endl;
  //std::cout << b.Compute<bool>(true, false) << std::endl; --> compile error
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT1**

Do class template specialization for `Base` class to achieve the results. Create a full specialization for `OpType::BITWISE` and implement your `Compute` function.

```
#include <iostream>

enum class OpType{
  INT,
  BITWISE,
};

template <OpType T>
class Base{
 public:
  template <typename U>
  typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, bool>::value, U>::type Compute(U a, U b);
};

template<OpType T>
template<typename U>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, bool>::value, U>::type
Base<T>::Compute(U a, U b){
  return a + b;
}

template <>
struct Base<OpType::BITWISE> {
  template <typename U>
  U Compute(U a, U b) { return a & b;}
};

using AddOperation = Base<OpType::INT>;
using AndOperation = Base<OpType::BITWISE>;

int main(){
  AddOperation b;
  AndOperation a;
  std::cout << b.Compute<int>(10, 2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << a.Compute<bool>(true, true) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, Thanks. Though I had added another requirement to my problem. Would love to know your input on the same.